# Square of integrable function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then so is $f^2$ using the fact that $|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|\leq 2M|f(x)-f(y)|$ for $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $U(f^2,P) - L(f^2,P) \leq 2M\cdot(U(f,P) - L(f,P))$ for a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_a^b f^2(x) dx \\ \leq \int_a^b |f^2(x) -f^2(y) + f^2(y)|dx\\ \leq \int_a^b |f^2(x)-f^2(y)| +f^2(y) dx \\ \leq2M\int_a^b|f(x)-f(y)|dx + C(b-a) \\ \leq2M\int_a^b|f(x)| + 2C(b-a) <\infty $$